# SPARQL: How can I group multiple fields?

Tags: sparql, relationship, rdf

I'm trying to use the GROUP BY  and GROUP_CONCAT functions to group my results into single rows for each entity but I cannot make it work.

This is what I have: a Project has a Name and can have multiple Topics and Areas.

When I do this query:

```
SELECT ?proj ?name ?topic ?area
WHERE {
    ?proj hasName ?name .
    ?proj hasTopic ?topic .
    ?proj hasArea ?area .
}
```

I get this table of bindings:

| proj | name | topic | area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uri | My Project | building | Europe |
| uri | My Project | building | Asia |
| uri | My Project | park | Europe |
| uri | My Project | park | Asia |

But what I would want is:

| proj | name | topic | area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uri | My Project | building, park | Europe, Asia |

I've tried using:

```
SELECT ?proj ?name
(GROUP_CONCAT(?topic; separator=", ") AS ?topics)
(GROUP_CONCAT(?area; separator=", ") AS ?areas)
WHERE {
    ?proj hasName ?name .
    ?proj hasTopic ?topic .
    ?proj hasArea ?area .
}
GROUP BY ?proj ?name
```

But I get the topics doubled: `building, building, park, park`.

What am I missing? How should I approach this?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path, but you just need to use the `DISTINCT` keyword. The following works for me.

```
SELECT ?proj ?name
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?topic; separator=", ") AS ?topics)
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?area; separator=", ") AS ?areas)
WHERE {
    ?proj hasName ?name .
    ?proj hasTopic ?topic .
    ?proj hasArea ?area .
}
GROUP BY ?proj ?name
```

Comment: Yes! That was it. Also, I used MIN on ?name instead of putting it in the GROUP BY clause, to avoid duplicates.

Comment: You can also use `SAMPLE`, which may perform better.